# Proving a statement using induction

Tags: logic, proof-writing, induction

Use the principle of Mathematical Induction to show:
$$\sum _ { k = 1 } ^ { n } k x ^ { k - 1 } = \frac { 1 - ( n + 1 ) x ^ { n } + n x ^ { n + 1 } } { ( 1 - x ) ^ { 2 } }$$
for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$

I understand the concept of induction in general, but I'm not sure how to use induction in this scenario

Comment: without induction, note: $f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^n x^k=\frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x} \Rightarrow f'(x)=\sum_{k=1}^n kx^{k-1}=...$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint.** First, note that the statement is trivially true for $n=0$ under the interpretation $\sum_{k=1}^{0}f(k)=0$ (and $0^0 = 1$ if $x=0$).
This the base case.
As for the inductive case, suppose the statement holds for some *particular* positive integer $n$.
Then,
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}kx^{k-1}
=\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}kx^{k-1}\right)+\left(n+1\right)x^{n}
=\frac{1-\left(n+1\right)x^{n}+nx^{n+1}}{\left(1-x\right)^{2}}+\left(n+1\right)x^{n}.
$$
I leave it to you to massage the rightmost expression in the above equality into the form
$$
\frac{1-\left(n+2\right)x^{n+1}+\left(n+1\right)x^{n+2}}{\left(1-x\right)^{2}},
$$
establishing the inductive case.
Now, conclude by the principle of induction.

It's good practice to point out that the claim is meaningless at $x=1$.

Comment: Im not sure how you would simplify the expression: $\frac { 1 - ( n + 1 ) x ^ { n } + n x ^ { n + 1 } } { ( 1 - x ) ^ { 2 } } + ( n + 1 ) x ^ { n }$

Comment: Multiply the second term by $$1=\frac{(1-x)^2}{(1-x)^2}$$ and then combine the resulting fractions.

Comment: \begin{align*}
1-\left(n+1\right)x^{n}+nx^{n+1}+\left(n+1\right)x^{n}\left(1-x\right)^{2} & =1+\left(-n-1\right)x^{n}+nx^{n+1}+\left(n+1\right)x^{n}\left(1-x\right)^{2}\\
 & =1+\left(-n-1\right)x^{n}+nx^{n+1}+\left(n+1\right)x^{n}\left(1-2x+x^{2}\right)\\
 & =1+\left(-n-1\right)x^{n}+nx^{n+1}+\left(n+1\right)x^{n}-2\left(n+1\right)x^{n+1}+\left(n+1\right)x^{n+2}\\
 & =1+\left(-n-1+n+1\right)x^{n}+\left(n-2n-2\right)x^{n+1}+\left(n+1\right)x^{n+2}\\
 & =1+\left(-n-2\right)x^{n+1}+\left(n+1\right)x^{n+2}\\
 & =1-\left(n+2\right)x^{n+1}+\left(n+1\right)x^{n+2}
\end{align*}

Comment: ...so much for "I leave it to you"...

Comment: @GrahamKemp: Woops :/